# Is the graph of $y= |x|$ the graph of a smooth function?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, smooth-functions

Is there a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that the image is the graph of $f(x) =|x|$ ?

Comment: What is the reason for the downvotes?

Comment: maybe it's because the question has no context, is it a homework question? in that case, you should show your attempts.

Comment: Or maybe it's because of the title. The question in the title is not the same as the question in the body of the post - the answer to the question in the title is _obviously_ no...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  The question in the title is not even false, as they say, but I read it to mean the question in the body. I think I'll edit it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes: take $f(x) = (|x|x,x^2) = (\mathop{\rm sign}(x)x^2,x^2)$. The key fact is that the function $f_1(x)=|x|x$ is differentiable everywhere.

More generally, let $g\colon [0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ be any surjective function with $g(0)=0$; then the image of $f(x) = (\mathop{\rm sign}(x)g(x^2),g(x^2))$ is the graph of $y=|x|$. In particular, if $g$ is chosen to be very smooth everywhere and have derivatives of all order equal to $0$ at $x=0$, then $f$ will be very smooth as well.

Comment: Hmm. Of course $|x|x$ is not actually _smooth_...

Comment: What's your notion of 'very smooth' ?

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x) = (xe^{-1/x^2},|x|e^{-1/x^2}),$ then $f$ is $C^\infty$ and a homeomorphism of $\mathbb R$ onto the graph of $y=|x|.$